# How to handle un-named parameters when one can be piped

Tags: parsing, powershell, parameters

I want my Powershell script to be able to handle two parameter sets as shown below.

Set 1:

- Param1: `GroupName` via pipe
- Param2: `FilePath`
- Called like: `"GROUPNAME" | script.ps1 FilePath`

Set 2:

- Param1: `GroupName`
- Param2: `FilePath`
- Called like: `script.ps1 GroupName FilePath`

In both cases both arguments are mandatory.

I have tried everything I can think of and the closest I think I have gotten is this:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Pipe")]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$false,HelpMessage="AD Group Name",ParameterSetName="Param")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,HelpMessage="AD Group Name",ParameterSetName="Pipe")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]$GroupName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1,ValueFromPipeline=$false,HelpMessage="Path to CSV",ParameterSetName="Param")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$false,HelpMessage="Path to CSV",ParameterSetName="Pipe")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]$FilePath
)
```

This does not work, as it always expect the second argument at position 1; any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two parameter sets. `ValueFromPipeline=$true` makes the function *accept* input from the pipeline, but doesn't *require* that it come from the pipeline - it can be specified as an argument just as well.

Comment: I understand that, the problem is that I would like both arguments to be able to be passed without a flag (-FilePath) and in an example where GroupName is passed via a piipe powershell still expects something at position 1 but FilePath has moved to position 0.

Comment: I see what you mean. The problem with using parameter sets to solve this is that each parameter set has to have at least one unique parameter that identifies it, otherwise PowerShell gets confused about which parameter set should be used. All I can suggest is to reverse the order of the parameters (FilePath first), and don't use parameter sets. Then either `"GROUPNAME" | script.ps1 FilePath` or `script.ps1 FilePath GroupName` will work.